# Hibernate does not insert a value into the database

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, pojo

I've started learning Hibernate and ran into a problem: when I try to insert a value into my Postgres DB, it just disappears. I can not understand what I do wrong.

Here my POJO I try to upload

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dog", schema = "public", catalog = "TestDogAndOwnerDB")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Dog implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

Here my xml-file with properties.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres</property>
        <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="connection.password">*****</property>
        <property name="connection.characterEncoding">utf8</property>
        <property name="show_sql"> true </property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <mapping class="Entity.Dog"/>
        <mapping class="Entity.Owner"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Here my DogHelper class

```
import Entity.Dog;
import Entity.Owner;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import jakarta.persistence.Persistence;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

import java.util.List;

public class DogHelper {
    private final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public DogHelper() {
        sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    }

    public Dog getDogByID(Long id) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        if (session == null) {
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        }
        return session.get(Dog.class, id);
    }

    public void putDogIntoDB(Dog dog) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        if (session == null) {
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        }
        try {
            session.getTransaction().begin();
            session.persist(dog);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }

    }
}
```

The main function.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        DogHelper dogHelper = new DogHelper();
        Dog dog = new Dog();
        dog.setName("Archi");
        dogHelper.putDogIntoDB(dog);
    }
```

When I try to upload the POJO, everything goes fine, but then I check my DB and there is nothing inside!  Maybe something is wrong with it, I don't know.

**EDIT:**
Found out, that Hibernate tries to put all data in one column "name". It follows from the sql query Hibernate produces --

```
insert into public.dog (name) values (?)
```

I have no idea why this happens.

Comment: I don't see where you call `putDogIntoDB`.

Comment: Sure I do. Edited the question.

Comment: What shows up in the logs - are there SQL statements and information on the transaction being started and committed? How are you checking the database, and can you 'find' the entity you inserted with a read all query in the same session context?

Comment: I used "SELECT * ..." statement, checked the datebase from pg4Admin and from the inside of IDEA. No data at all. I saw this SQL query in the logs:   Hibernate: 
    /* insert Entity.Dog
        */ insert 
    into
        public.dog (name) 
    values
        (?)